# Including a file with PHP - avoiding not found?

Tags: php

I am new to php, I have two files, one where I want to keep my classes and bulk of my code, and another where I integrate with some HTML. My code was working, but now I am getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'bardrink' not found in C:\MAMP\htdocs\index.view.php:84 Stack trace: > #0 {main}   thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\index.view.php on line 84

Here is my index.php file:

```
<?php

class bardrink {
    public $drink_name;
    public $drink_desc;
    public $drink_strength;
    public $drink_price;

    public function __construct($drink_name,$drink_desc,$drink_strength,$drink_price)

    {
      $this->drink_name = $drink_name;
      $this->drink_desc = $drink_desc;
      $this->drink_strength = $drink_strength;
      $this->drink_price = $drink_price;
    }
  }

require 'index.view.php';

 ?>
```

And in my index.view.php I am adding:

```
<?php

    $barselection = [
      new bardrink('Water','A light refreshing drink.',0,1),
      new bardrink('Light Ale','A pale ale brewed locally.',2,4),
      new bardrink('Mulled Wine','A warm festive wine, perfect for a chilly evening!',3,6),
      new bardrink('Dark Ale','A strange frothy, dark liquid...',5,10)
    ];

    var_dump($barselection)

?>
```

I've required the index.view.php in the index file, but I do I need to add a require into my view file also to make this work?

Comment: Try instead: require the index.php file at the beginning of your index.view.php file.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, can it not work the other way?

Comment: Please check out the PHP PSR guidelines. Firstly, they contain formatting rules, which make it easier for others to read your code. Further, there is a guideline that a file should *either* declare things (classes, functions, constants) *or* cause sideeffects, but not both. Thus, you should switch the direction of the includes.

Comment: @BenP The latter part of this answer may shed some light on the difference for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27436354/3303195