# PHP | random order includes file

Tags: php

I have files included in a code.

the logic is that these files contain information that the user has to view (communications), the goal of these 20 files is that they should be shown to the user in random order.

Now the code calculates the user registration date and based on the days that have passed it shows the file that must be seen by the user

```
<?php
// Declare and define two dates
$date1 = strtotime($data_registrazione);
$date2 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

// Formulate the Difference between two dates
$diff = abs($date2 - $date1);


// To get the year divide the resultant date into
// total seconds in a year (365*60*60*24)
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));


// To get the month, subtract it with years and
// divide the resultant date into
// total seconds in a month (30*60*60*24)
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24)
    / (30*60*60*24));


// To get the day, subtract it with years and
// months and divide the resultant date into
// total seconds in a days (60*60*24)
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 -
        $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

?>
<?php if ($days == 0) :?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_zero.php'; ?>
<?php elseif ($days == 1) :?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_uno.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 2) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_due.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 3) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_tre.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 4) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_quattro.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 5) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_cinque.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 6) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_sei.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 7) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_sette.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 8) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_otto.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 9) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_nove.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 10) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_dieci.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 11) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_undici.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 12) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_dodici.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 13) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_tredici.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 14) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_quattoridic.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 15) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_quindici.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 16) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_sedici.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 17) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_diciassette.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 18) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_diciotto.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 19) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_diciannove.php'; ?>
<?php elseif($days == 20) : ?>
    <?php include 'referrer_pro/giorno_venti.php'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

how can i change the structure no longer to show a different file based on the past days.

But does it show files in random order regardless of the days that have passed?

Comment: That is quite unorganised... Try switch statements

Comment: Put all your file paths in an array and pick a random element.

Comment: I assume you have thought about renaming the files using `giorno_0.php` instead of `giorno_zero.php` and then this would be Ezzie Peezy

Comment: Also there is Absolutely No Need to put `<?php .. ?>` around every line of consecutive code!! Makes the code almost unreadable and unmaintainable

Comment: @El_Vanja how to array files and choose random order?

Comment: Literally, manually. Take all the file path strings and put them in an array. I assume you know how to search for "pick a random array element". Include the picked one and you're done.

Comment: @El_Vanja that is not a problem, I was reflecting on the fact that if I did this, by removing the structure: "calculate what day has passed", it would mean that at each refresh of the page, the user would see a different random, correct?

Comment: @El_Vanja I was thinking how to say, calculate from the day of registration, infinite days and put random files, because now it reaches up to 20 days

Comment: Now I am completely lost. I don't understand your requirements. Do you need users to see a randomly picked file, but see the same file within the day? And then tomorrow another one?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes Because now it calculates how many days have passed since the registration date and shows the file up to 20 days, but I would need to calculate an infinite number of days from the registration date and for each day it shows a file in random order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does PHP required or included files need to follow the order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436210/does-php-required-or-included-files-need-to-follow-the-order)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$input = array('referrer_pro/giorno_zero.php', 'referrer_pro/giorno_uno.php', 'referrer_pro/giorno_due.php', 'referrer_pro/giorno_tre.php', 'referrer_pro/giorno_quattro.php');
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
include $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
include $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
```

This is how to put all the files path in an array and to pick them randomly. If you replace the 2 in the array_rand code with the array length then you will get all of them randomly. PHP in a single code execution will not pick the same element twice.

Comment: Lelio, thanks for your answer, I was wondering how I wrote in the answer comment: I was reflecting on the fact that if I did this, by removing the structure: "calculate what day has passed", it would mean that at each refresh of the page, the user would see a different random, correct?  I was thinking how to say, calculate from the day of registration, infinite days and put random files, because now it reaches up to 20 days

Comment: why you should remove the section about the "calculate what days have passed"? What I am saying is that once you get the array with your code you can display the 20 files in a random order. Then you can adapt the code to extract less files or more as you prefer. Btw your actual code makes little sense on a functional side but that's just my humble opinion

Comment: I would not want to remove it completely, on the contrary add a piece of code, which calculates me no longer up to 20 days from the date of registration, but infinite days from the date of registration and every day choose a file in random order

Comment: prevents me, that I am not able to do it :(

Comment: applying the code of your answer does not even show me the contents of the file, but only the name of the include

Comment: my code is just an example that you need to adapt to your needs. Anyway I'd suggest you to completely rephrase your question to explain what you really need if you want to get a proper help. This way it is way too broad.

Comment: just for an example, just replacing echo with include will give you the replacement of your actual code

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the roughly random number like you say you want but that will work for any number of days from the registration date, what you need to do is get the Modulo 20 of the days difference.

The diff calc can also be simplified to this

```
# change the format to match how your date is being presented to this code
$regDate = (new DateTime())->createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2000-11-16');
$diff = $regDate->diff(new DateTime());
$days = $diff->days % 20;
echo "Random_ish number less than or equal to 20 = $days";
```

So you can use `$days` as you currently do.