# Add multiple class files before executing PHP

Tags: php, file, class

Say I have a folder with 3 classes, 1 extends a class and the other one implements the interface.
These classfiles have names like {class}.class.php.

Is it possible to include these files in any order without returning an error, normally you first need the base class, then the extended class and then the interface class, if in the wrong order, the second class cannot find the first class.

I want to include them at once from calling the folder in a single function, but prevent them from executing before all are loaded in the memory. So even if the second class is added first as a file, it still won't start looking for the other class until all classfiles are added.

Would a setup like that be possible?

-- **I solved the issue using the following solution** --

Since I was using Composer (for PHPMailer), which had an autoload, it would have been madness to not use that one, instead of adding a seperate class I added my folders to the *composer.json*.

Like this:

```
{
    "require": {        
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.5"
    },
      "autoload": {
        "classmap":
          ["php/class/", "module/login/class/"]
    }
}
```

Then I ran composer in the console, with the command `composer dump-autoload`.

It auto-generated the file: `/vendor/autoload_classmap.php` like this:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Composer\\InstalledVersions' => $vendorDir . '/composer/InstalledVersions.php',
    'FixedBitNotation' => $baseDir . '/module/login/class/FixedBitNotation.class.php',
    'authenticate' => $baseDir . '/module/login/class/authenticate.class.php',
    'authenticateInterface' => $baseDir . '/module/login/class/authenticate.interface.php',
    'data' => $baseDir . '/php/class/data.class.php',
    'form' => $baseDir . '/php/class/form.class.php',
    'login' => $baseDir . '/module/login/class/login.class.php',
    'loginInterface' => $baseDir . '/module/login/class/login.interface.php',
);
```

Now simple by including autoload I can use all classes, even without the namespace/use.

`include(BASEDIR .'/vendor/autoload.php');`

Many thanks for the helpful comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does PHP required or included files need to follow the order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436210/does-php-required-or-included-files-need-to-follow-the-order). Looking into [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) so that you don’t have to think about this.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php